# How to update already existing data using token only?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to complete a `login/Sign Up API` using **Node Js and MongoDB**, and everything works fine except `Forgot Password`. I send an email to the user with a link to add new password.
The issue I am having is, How will I extract that specific user when he/she presses the reset button and only update that user's data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Classic rest password should have this flow:

- user select the reset password
- user enter its mail
- a mail is sent from the system
- mail contains a link (with expiration time for security) something like this:

```
https://acme.com/security/password/reset?code=8df024dfd526
```

- `code=8df024dfd526` in the link is related to the mail, so when is clicked, a final UI form will be prompted to the user. You could use this code to identify the email, sending it to your backend
- **You cannot ask the email again because anyone could change anyone's password**.
- Some times this code is known as **one-time password (OTP)**.

  - As its name says: You must ensure that this code works just one time. I mean if user click again, you should show an error.
  - More details [here](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/one-time-password-OTP).

### implementation

You just need to persist somewhere (database) the following information:

- the generated alphanumeric code with the requested email.
- an expiration time for any code
- usage count of code

Comment: Thanks a lot Man. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your email link to the user should be unique and can identify the user.

I do this:

```js
// Generate hashed reset password token
User.resetPasswordToken = (user) => {
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
  // Update user with hashed token and expire time
  user.resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex')
  user.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000
  // Return unhashed token for use in email url
  return resetToken
}
```

Here I do two things: 1) update the User in the DB with a resetPasswordToken and an expiration time/date for the resetPassword. Both saved in the database. 2) return an unhashed resetPassword for use in the email link to be sent (see below).

```js
    const resetToken = User.resetPasswordToken(user)
    await user.save()

    const resetUrl = `<a href="${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/api/${process.env.API_VERSION}/auth/password/${resetToken}">this link</a>`

    // Send email
    const message = `<p>Please follow ${resetUrl} in order to create a new password. The link is valid for 10 minutes.</p>`
```

User now clicks the link and the endpoint extracts the reset token, hashes it and checks if it corresponds with the token saved on this particular user in the database from `req.params.resettoken`:

```js
const resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.params.resettoken).digest('hex')

  const timeNow = Date.now()
  let user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      resetPasswordToken,
      deletedAt: null,
    },
  })
```

Then I perform some checks before I save the new password (encrypted) the user has typed in. I reset the reset token and expiration password in the database to null.

```js
  user.password = await encrypt(req.body.password)
  user.resetPasswordToken = null
  user.resetPasswordExpire = null
  try {
    await user.save()
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`The new password could not be saved, please try again later`, 500))
  }
```